# How to use freemarker comments to add IE conditional comments?

Tags: html, dom, freemarker, conditional-comments

I have freemarker templates with IE conditional comments. After the templates become html templates I still see the other IE conditional comments. So I'm trying to clean up my templates by using freemarker comments so that the unused conditional comments don't show up in html files. This is the syntax for freemarker comments: <#-- comments -->. The benefit of using freemarker comments is that the other unused comments will be hidden from the DOM tree.

```
<html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="no-js ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><!--<![endif]-->
<head>...</head>
```

This is what I've tried. It doesn't work.

```
<#--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <#[endif]-->
<#--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <#[endif]-->
<#--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js ie lt-ie9" xmlns:ng="" id="ng-app"> <#[endif]-->
<#--[if IE 9]>         <html class="no-js ie" xmlns:ng="" id="ng-app"> <#[endif]-->
<#--[if gt IE 9]><#--> <html class="no-js" xmlns:ng="" id="ng-app"><#--<#[endif]-->
```

Comment: If you do it from the server side, you're not going to want to do it via comments. You're going to want to find out the browser type/version in code, then use conditional statements depending on what the result is. See the [Freemarker reference on using the if directive](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html#autoid_8).

Comment: How would you find out browser type/version in the server side without the help of javascript?

Comment: Each browser sends some information about itself to the web server, and in this case you're looking for the user-agent string. The web server would have to filter [only the IE versions you want](http://useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/) then pass that as a variable to [Freemaker's data model](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_directive.html). From what it looks like, Freemaker doesn't deal with http headers (the extra browser data) meaning you'll probably need to [set up a web server with Freemaker](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html) if you haven't already.